# Sum of the ratios of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I find the sum of the following ratio of binomial coefficient
$$
\sum_{j=k}^n \frac{ {j \choose k} }{ {n \choose j}}
$$

I found a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530642/prove-that-sum-k-0m-frac-binommk-binomnk-fracn1n1-m) similar to mine but differs in the summation index. Is there a general strategy for finding the sum of binomial coefficients?

Comment: For $k=0$, see [Calculate sums of inverses of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151441/318073).

Comment: This seems like a job for Zeilberger algorithm.

Comment: It only finds 2nd-order recurrence (w.r.t. $n$ or $k$, separately).