# An interesting binomial summation

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

Recently, a student asked this summation
$$
S= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n \choose k}}{ {m + n-1 \choose k}}
$$
without putting any effort. Interestingly, opening of the binomial coefficient doesn't seem to help, yet it is doable.

Use
$$
{N\choose k}^{-1}=(N+1)\int_{0}^{1} x^k(1-x)^{N-k}\, dx.
$$
Then
$$
S= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n \choose k}}{ {m + n-1 \choose k}}= (m+n) \sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{1} {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{m+n-1}\, dx
$$
$$\implies S=(m+n)\int_{0}^{1}\, dx~
(1-x)^{m+n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k$$
$$\implies S=(m+n)\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{m-1}dx=\frac{m+n}{m}.$$

> The question is: How to do it otherwise?

Comment: Maybe use [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E4) along with hypergeometric reduction formulae?

Comment: This looks like it might be a duplicate of [Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{\binom{m}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{n+1}{n+1-m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530642/prove-that-sum-k-0m-frac-binommk-binomnk-fracn1n1-m).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Opening of the binomial coefficient indeed works.
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n \choose k}}{ {m + n-1 \choose k}}\\=\frac{n!}{(m+n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(m+n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!}\\=\frac{n!(m-1)!}{(m+n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(m+n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!(m-1)!}\\=\frac{n!(m-1)!}{(m+n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n {m+n-k-1 \choose m-1}\\=\frac{n!(m-1)!}{(m+n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n {m+k-1 \choose m-1} $$
We know that,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {m+k-1 \choose m-1}={m-1 \choose m-1}+{m \choose m-1}+\cdots +{m+n-1 \choose m-1}={m+n \choose m}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n \choose k}}{ {m + n-1 \choose k}}=\frac{n!(m-1)!}{(m+n-1)!}\cdot{m+n \choose m}=\frac{m+n}m$$

Comment: Great answer, in the ffourt step invoking $k \to n-k$ would have been a little better.